# UILabel with UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

Is there a way to have `UILabels` or `UITextViews` with `UIButtons`?

Example1: "This **Car** is yellow and has 4 wheels."

Where **Car** is the `UIButton` and can be anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: Well, if i'm not mistake, you're looking to add tappable text within `UILabel`s. A better approach would be to use [TTTAttibutedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). Just go through the link, and you'll know how to add links to specific words within your labels, and also invoke your own selectors on selecting those words.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh nice. I will try this.

Comment: With `UITextView`, you can use `NSAttributedString` and `NSLinkAttributeName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSAttributedString` with links at the ranges you want, and display them in [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). You can then get a callback whenever a link is tapped.

Comment: I want uibuttons to be able to call methods, i don't want to open links in the uiwebview. Or are you suggesting that i use links and parse them using the uiwebview delegate?

Comment: @bruno yep, have a custom link like custom-link://more-data-here and then check the scheme of the url in the delegate call

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a UITapGestureRecognizer to the label to detect the tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Then in your 'labelTapped:' selector method, you calculate the location of the tap within the frame of the label with the gesture object. You would then have to determine the location of the word in the label and see if the touch was in that CGRect.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with an app using UITextView.firstRectForRange method. This allows you to obtain the coordinates of text within the UITextView.

I used buttons and magic markers in the text. When rendering I located the magic markers and placed UIButtons over the top. e.g. @"This is the age of the $Train$" would place a button with title @"Train" over the marker.

You could also replace each marker with coloured text recording the locations using RectForRange. Then use touch gestures to see if any of the rectangles were selected.